# Switch case statement in PHP

Tags: php

I am learning PHP. I have downloaded an open source project from a website and looking the workflow of each modules in that project. I noticed a switch case which is unfamiliar to me.

```
switch ($value) {
        case 'student':
        case StudentClass::getInstance()->getId();
            return new StudentClass();
            break;
        case 'teacher':
        case TeacherClass::getInstance()->getId();
            return new TeacherClass();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

The above patch is what I looked. 
When I give input:

```
$value = 'student';
```

It returns **StudentClass** instance.

If I give

```
$value = 'teacher';
```

then it returns **TeacherClass** instance.

If anyone explain the flow, it will be helpful to me to understanding PHP much better

Comment: Nevermind, what is the issue? It's doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: no.. I didn't miss any statements. This is what I have seen in that module.

Comment: Each `case 'xx':` is the same as if you would do a `if($value =="xx"){ }` where `break;` is the end }

Comment: What is the problem, sounds it is working as expected..http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @chris85: Thanks. I am clear now. "It's possible to use a semicolon instead of a colon after a case like: "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string `cases` don't have `break` or `return` statements, so they "fall through" to the next `case`. Also, your `break`s don't serve any purpose here.

I've added comments to your code to explain what's happening.

```
switch ($value) {
        case 'student': // keeps going with next line
        case StudentClass::getInstance()->getId();
            return new StudentClass(); // handles both cases above
            break; // unnecessary because of the return above
        case 'teacher': // keeps going with next line
        case TeacherClass::getInstance()->getId();
            return new TeacherClass(); // handles both cases above
            break; // unnecessary because of the return above
        default:
            break; // pointless, but handles anything not already handled
}
```

Also, PHP explicitly allows use of a semicolon (`;`) after a `case`, but it is not generally considered good style. [From the docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

> It's possible to use a semicolon instead of a colon after a case...

Comment: As syntax, case statement should be end with colon. But here I am seeing case with semicolon. Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: @JayVenkat see my edit. This is allowed, but it's unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement is used to perform different actions based on different conditions.
First we have a single expression n (most often a variable), that is evaluated once. The value of the expression is then compared with the values for each case in the structure. If there is a match, the block of code associated with that case is executed. Use break to prevent the code from running into the next case automatically. The default statement is used if no match is found.

```html
switch (n) {
    case label1:
        code to be executed if n=label1;
        break;  // if n=label1,break ends execution and exit from switch
    case label2:
        code to be executed if n=label2;
        break;  // if n=label2,break ends execution and exit from switch
    case label3:
        code to be executed if n=label3;
        break;  // if n=label3,break ends execution and exit from switch
    ...
    default:
        code to be executed if n is different from all labels;
}
```